# How can I make a for-each to select all elements from an XML with variable tag names

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <name1>
    <tag1>name1value1</tag1>
    <tag2>name1value2</tag2>
  </name1>
  <name2>
    <tag1>name2value1</tag1>
    <tag2>name2value2</tag2>
  </name2>
</root>
```

I need to select every name*/tag* values. I tried using * or like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/*[starts-with(name(), 'name')]/child::*">
```

It just doesn't work... Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't work" means? Your code selects all the `tagX' nodes in your example.

Comment: The for-each code is not executed...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the code is working, I just made another mistake and couldn't see the results properly. Should I close this or just leave it here as an example?

Comment: If the issue is resolved, you can 1) delete the question or 2) [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and later self-accept) the question. But 2) would also require you to edit the question and include the information that is _necessary_ to solve the problem.